# If X is a Geometric random variable with parameter p, find p that maximizes P(X=k)

Tags: probability, statistics

The full question is,

> If X is a Geometric random variable with parameter p, what value of k ∈ {1, 2, . . .}
>   maximizes P(X = k) = (1 − p)^(k-1) * p? This is referred to as the mode of the distribution.

Through trial and error (plugging in random values), I found that p = 1/2 yields the highest value of P(X=k).

Is there a way to figure this out without trial and error?

Comment: You are supposed to find k which maximizes P(X=k) for some given p, not to find p which maximizes P(X=k) for some given k. (Anecdotally, your solution to the latter is wrong.)

Comment: @Did Whoops, read the question wrong. 

What would be the correct answer to the latter though?

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed $p \in (0,1)$, what can you say about the ratio $$\frac{\Pr[X = k+1]}{\Pr[X = k]} = \frac{(1-p)^{k} p}{(1-p)^{k-1} p}?$$  What does this suggest about the sequence of probabilities $\{\Pr[X = k]\}_{k \ge 1}$?  There is a **reason** why this is called a **geometric** distribution.  What happens to such a sequence when the **common ratio** is between $0$ and $1$?